# Insert To Table 180 Times, Incrementing Daily

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to insert a number of records, one for each of the next 180 days (each record is the same except for the date).  I'm not 100% what the best approach is, but I've attempted the following:

```
insert into [table]
select 12, DateAdd(d, row_number() - 1, GETDATE()), 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2
where row_number() < 180
```

This of course complains that I'm not using `OVER`, but I don't know how it would fit in this context.  Perhaps I'm thinking about this problem the wrong way at a higher level.

Any ideas on the best approach to do this?

The SQL Server type in question is MSSQL.

Comment: Would love an explanation for the downvote...

Comment: Seem like a fine question to me. Only missing thing is the kind and version of the database. I answered assuming SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have SQL Server and are willing to put start and end dates in the CTE below:

```
with dateranger as
(
    -- put start date here or use getdate()
    select cast('2013-01-01' as datetime) as date_of_interest
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, date_of_interest)
    from dateranger
    where dateadd(day, 1, date_of_interest) <= '2013-02-28'
    -- put end date above or use dateadd(d, 180, getdate())
)
insert into your_table
    select 12, date_of_interest, 0, null, null, null, 2 from dateranger
```

This will create a date-range table using the CTE and insert the relevant dates in the table.

Comment: Awesome, I like this one because it doesn't require an additional table.

Comment: It's worth noting you get a sql recursion error if you go beyond 100 days, I've discovered.

Comment: Good observation @GrantH! `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)` is a helpful hint in case of [cte recursion](http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/recursive-cte-maximum-recursion-100-has-been-exhausted/).

Answer (score 3):

[Numbers table!](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql)

```
INSERT INTO your_table (list, of, fields, ..., date_field )
SELECT list
     , of
     , fields
     , ...
     , DateAdd(dd, number, Current_Timetstamp)
FROM   dbo.numbers
WHERE  number BETWEEN 1 AND 180
```

Assuming you wan't a date without time portion (i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000`)

```
SELECT DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, Current_Timestamp), 0) As date_with_time_truncated
```

Just swap the `Current_Timestamp` in the first query with the above!